# Remove columns with NULL values from QGIS print layout attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts, printing, null

I have an attribute table in my QGIS print layout that only includes features within the map extent. I want that table to only show columns that have non-NULL values for that feature set, i.e. if the column has all NULL values then don't display that column. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In the Print layout's `Item Properties` of the attribute table,

- check the box `Show only features visible within a map` and select the respective map and
- check the box `Filter with` and insert this expression `"value" is not NULL`

*Attribute table with only the features visible in the map; the yellow points have content of `NULL` for the field `value` and are thus excluded from the attribute table:*
[image]